# MySQL table bigger than 1 TB on Google cloud Sql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google cloud MySQL.

I have one instance with 500 GB of space.

But now I need more space (let's say one more TB).

How can I use one MySQL table to store data on more than one instance ?

Comment: You should consider to shard your data. Several different techniques for sharding are out there, MySQL should have OTB support with Fabric. https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/fabric/faq.html, here a link to the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google second generation cloud sql is providing  10 TB Storage capacity per instance.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not supported. You have to shard your table horizontally manually in your own code to achieve that.